# Word splitting with regular expressions in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell

There are several packages available for the usage of regular expressions in Haskell (e.g. Text.Regex.Base, Text.Regex.Posix etc.). Most packages I've seen so far use a subset of Regex I know, by which I mean: I am used to split a sentence into words with the following Regex:

```
\\w+
```

Nearly all packages in Haskell I tried so far don't support this (at least the earlier mentioned and Text.Regex.TDFA neither). I know that with Posix the usage of [[:word:]+] would have the same effect, but I would like to use the variant mentioned above.

From there are two questions:

1. Is there any package to archive that?
2. If there really is, why is there a different common usage?
3. What advantages or disadvantages are there?

Comment: Do you require regular expressions to split the words?  There's a function `words` that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that function but it doesn't do what I want. If there are any dots, commas etc. in a string the Regex would ignore them but `words` would attach them. E.g.:
`Prelude> words "Just a simple test."` would result `["Just","a","simple","test."]`
I want it without the dot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The '\w' is a Perl pattern, and supported by PCRE, which you can access in Haskell with my [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre) package or the [pcre-light](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light) library.  If your input is a list of Char then the 'words' function in the standard Prelude may be enough; if your input is ASCII bytestring then [Data.ByteString.Char8](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.2.0/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#g:14) may work.  There may be a utf8 library with word splitting, but I cannot quickly find it.

Answer (score 13):

I'd use Adam's suggestion or (perhaps more readable)

```
> :m +Data.Char
> :m +Data.List.Split
> wordsBy (not . isLetter) "Just a simple test."
["Just","a","simple","test"]
```

No need in regexps here.

Comment: Just a note. Splitting into a words is not equal to that. For example, `wordsBy (not . isLetter) "I wanna have 14 balls."` returning `["I","wanna","have","balls"]`, but `14` can be a word actually.

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ This is not supposed to be a complete answer. Actually `\w` is `letters ++ digits ++ "_"` so `not . isLetter` is just a placeholder. I wanted to show easy and understandable splitting pattern.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to break into words, and filter out things other than letters, you could use filter and `isAlpha` or `isAlphaNum` (or any of the other `is` functions in `Data.Char` that suite your need.)

```
import Data.Char

wordsButOnlyLetters = map (filter isAlpha) . words
```

Answer (score 3):

words function works well, but it's more like 'split by white space', use splitRegex.

```
import Text.Regex (splitRegex, mkRegex)

splitByWord :: String -> [String]
splitByWord = splitRegex (mkRegex "[^a-zA-Z]+")

>splitByWord "Word splitting with regular expressions in Haskell"
>["Word","splitting","with","regular","expressions","in","Haskell"]
```

Comment: `Could not find module ‘Text.Regex’
    Perhaps you meant Text.Read`